# Какую технологию выбрать для работы SVG или Canvas?

Tags: svg, canvas

SVG или Canvas? Помогите сравнить эти две почти параллельные технологии.На чем стоит остановить свой выбор?

Comment: Это ты спрашиваешь потому что обе технологии знаешь или не знаешь?)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В развитии инструментов работы с изображением уже достаточно давно (еще до появления современных компьютерных систем) параллельно существуют два подхода: работа с вектором (например, чертежи) и работа с точками (например, живопись). В SVG и Canvas происходит очередное воплощение этих подходов.

SVG. Формат описания векторной графики средствами XML. При использовании в HTML5 SVG является частью DOM и операции доступные над DOM доступны над SVG. Отлично подходит для создания сложных интерфейсов, простых анимаций и т.д.

Canvas. Это API по работе с холстом. При работе в HTML5 Canvas является просто частью экрана над которой определены операции рисования по массиву точек. Отлично подходит для интенсивной графики - 2D игр, сложных анимаций и т.п.

Разница по сути в том, что в SVG нарисованная линия так и остается линией, а в Canvas она переходит в массив точек на холсте. Поэтому при манипуляциях с отдельными постоянными элементами удобнее SVG, а при манипуляциях со множеством быстро меняющихся элементов удобнее Canvas.